# replace (,) in place of (.) in textview in android

Tags: android

I am using this code to add two number after (. in my number. For example: I have string 14.3, so I want to get 14.30, when get 14 I want to get 14.00. This is code:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
tvPrice.setText(addDolar(format.format(Double.parseDouble(alerts.getPrice()))));

private String addDolar(String amount) {
    if(amount.startsWith("-")) {
         return "-$ "+amount.substring(1, amount.length());
    }
    else
        return "$ "+amount;
}
```

problem is that I want to get '.' and now i get ','.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace it:

```
someDouble.toString().replace(",", "."))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add two precisions only, then try this code

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
String formatted = format.format(your_value);
editText.setText(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
public double round(double unrounded)
{
      BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
      BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

      return rounded.doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
tvPrice.setText(addDolar(format.format(Double.parseDouble(alerts.getPrice()))));

private String addDolar(String amount) 
{
    amount = amount.replace ( ",","." );                       // Add this line
    if(amount.startsWith("-")) 
    {
         return "-$ "+amount.substring(1, amount.length());
    }
    else
        return "$ "+amount;
}
```